# what difference between VS c++ and MinGW to implement double type

Tags: c++, double

The same code run in VS c++ and MinGW got different result. The result is type of double. Example: in VS c++ got "-6.397745731873350", but in MinGW got "-6.397745731873378". There was litter different. But I don't known why?

Comment: `double` type can only hold around 15 decimal digits of precision. Beyond that, there is no guarantee about the correctness.

Answer (score 3):

I'd hazard a guess that it's one of two possibilities.

Back when Windows NT was new, and they supported porting to other processors (e.g., MIPS and DEC Alpha), MS had a little bit of a problem: the processors all had 64-bit floating point types, but they sometimes generated slightly different results. The DEC Alpha did computation on a 64-bit double *as* a 64-bit double. The default mode on an x86 was a little different: as you loaded a floating point number, any smaller type was converted to its internal 80-bit extended double format. Then all computation was done in 80-bit precision. Finally, when you stored the value, it was rounded back to 64 bits. This meant two things: first, for single- and double-precision results, the Intel was quite a bit slower. Second, double precision results often differed slightly between the processors.

To fix those "problems", Microsoft set up their standard library to adjust the floating point processor to only use 64-bit precision instead of 80-bit. Even though they've long-since dropped all support for other processors, they still (at least the last time I looked, and I'd be surprised if it's changed) set the floating point processor to only work in 64-bit precision. I haven't checked to be sure, but I'd guess that MingW may leave the floating point processor set to its default 80-bit precision instead.

There's one other possible source of difference: if you were comparing a 32-bit compiler to a 64-bit compiler, you get a different (though still somewhat similar) situation. The 32-bit compilers (both Microsoft and gcc) use the x87-style floating registers and instructions. Microsoft's 64-bit compiler does not use the x87-style floating point though (at least by default). Instead, it uses SSE instructions. I haven't done a lot of testing with this either, but I wouldn't be surprised at all if (again) there's a slight difference between x87 and SSE when it comes to things like guard bits and rounding. I wouldn't expect big differences at all, but would consider some slight differences extremely likely (bordering on inevitable).

Comment: Is there any literature can help me insight the theory? the processor design principle?

Comment: The usual recommendation is [*Computer Architecture: A Quantitative Approach*](http://www.amazon.com/Computer-Architecture-Quantitative-Approach-Edition/dp/0123704901) by Hennessy and Patterson. I'm not very excited about it myself though. I think they ask good questions, but usually come up with poor answers. Unfortunately, I don't have a lot *better* book to recommend instead.

Answer (score 1):

Most floating-point numbers cannot be represented accurately by computers. They're approximation. There is a *certain degree of unreliability* in their representation. Different compilers may implement the *unreliability* differently. That is why you see those diffferences.

Read this excellent article:

- [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in the **Precision** in which MinGW and VS C++ can represent your floating point number..

> **What is Precision?**

*The precision of a floating point number is how many digits it can represent without losing any information it contains.*

Consider the fraction `1/3`. The decimal representation of this number is `0.33333333333333…` with 3′s going out to infinity. An infinite length number would require infinite memory to be depicted with exact precision, but `float` or `double` data types typically only have `4` or `8` bytes. Thus Floating point & double numbers can only store a certain number of digits, and the rest are bound to get lost. Thus, there is no definite accurate way of representing float or double numbers with numbers that require more precision than the variables can hold.

Comment: I think the explanation is a bit off. While it is true that the precision doesn't allow the digits pass a certain threshold to be reliable, the difference in the output probably is caused by the difference in how the implementation decides to display those unreliable digits.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Actually, it's not even a matter of display. x86 processors often perform operations on `double` with 80 bits precision, even though only 64 bits are available in the `double` type; therefore depending on when the number is passed from register to cache (back and forth) the results are slightly different... This not only depends on the compiler (though apparently MSVC adjusts the processor mode) but also on the generated code: between Debug and Release you will often observe different results on complicated computations for example.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Thanks for the correction. Jerry Coffin made a detailed explanation on the internal implementation of MSVC and MinGW, which covers similar point to your comment.

Comment: @MatthieuM. i want to insight the theory. Which material can I should read? And how can known the processors difference about perform operations on double.